# config.fog_host does not works fine for me with cdn's in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, fog

I have this in my **fog.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'key',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'key',
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1'
  }

  config.fog_host = proc { "http://cdn#{(rand * 4).ceil}.domain.com" }
  config.fog_directory = 'pro'
  config.fog_public = false
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'} 
end
```

But I see the images routes to https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pro...

However my assets js, css, and images assets works fine I see:

http://cdn0.domain.com/assets/logo-4cbddb290494d56e25f86fffa93f4b00.png

**What am I doing wrong in this config?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's enough info to really help you but I think I see one problem: in your proc, the .ceil should be a .floor. Otherwise, you'll never get cdn0